# About insufficient priority error

Tags: bitcoin-cash, sendrawtransaction

The input of UTXO transaction being used is 10 pieces, total 0.0082 BTC.
Broadcasting the fee at 0.000012 BTC (sendrawtransaction), the following error occurs.

```
insufficient priority
```

Is the fee setting not good?
I do not know the cause.

Answer (score 1):

That error means you did not provide a high enough transaction fee on your transaction.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I am using bitcoin abc client, how can I calculate the fee?

Comment: Using the transaction you have now, get its size in kb. Then you can use the `estimatesmartfee` command (read the help text for that command so you can use the correct arguments) to get a feerate in BCH/kb. Using that feerate, multiply it by the transaction size in kb that you got earlier. That's the fee you should pay. Then remake your transaction using that fee.

Comment: Since we are using bitcoin-abc client vertion 0.18.5 and there is no `estimatesmartfee`, i use` estimatefee` to calculate it.
Is it better to use use `estimatefee`?
After calculating the fee using `estimatefee`, it  insufficient priority error

Comment: Also, the calculation formula I use is below
`` `
(estimatefee result * transaction size) / 1000 = fee (btc)
`` `
Is this calculation wrong?